# java random numbers must be different

Tags: java

I'm creating a small program that extracts 3 random numbers, the only condition is that all three numbers must be different from each other, for example: 3,9,3 is not acceptable.

This i my code, i tried it several times and occasionally appear numbers equal to each other.

What is wrong in my code ?

```
public class Premi {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = (int) (Math.random() *10) + 1;
    int num2 = (int) (Math.random() *10) + 1;
    int num3 = (int) (Math.random() *10) + 1;
    boolean first = true;
    boolean second = true;
    boolean third = true;
    while(first) {
        if (num!=num2) {
            first=false;
        } else if (num==num2) {
            num = (int) (Math.random() *10) + 1;
        }   
    }
    while(second) {
        if (num!=num3) {
            second=false;
        } else if (num==num3) {
            num = (int) (Math.random() *10) + 1;
        }   
    }
    while(third) {
        if (num2!=num3) {
            third=false;
        } else if (num2==num3) {
            num2 = (int) (Math.random() *10) + 1;
        }   
    }
    System.out.println(num + "," + num2 + "," + num3);
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: Create a list. While this list's length is `< 3`, generate a random integer. If it's in the list, keep iterating. If it's not, add it to the list. Why all the checks like this?

Comment: i've done , but i can't find it

Comment: If you change `num2` in the last while loop, you might make it match `num` and you don't check this

Comment: Try SecureRandom this might reduce the no. of conflicts

Comment: yes but i can't use this code because, i'm studing java for first time ad i'm at chapter 5 of my book and until now on the book are explained the cycle and the if-else iteration

Comment: By the way: You don't need `if else` in your code. If `(num!=num2)` is `false` then `(num==num2)` must be `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
while (numbers.size() < 3)
    numbers.add(((int) (Math.random() *10) + 1));
```

Using `Set` here will guarantee that the numbers are not repeating.

And if you're not allowed to use any collections or arrays (I'll reserve my opinion of courses that forbid students to use valid techniques) you can use:

```
int n1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
int n2;
do {
    n2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
} while (n2 == n1);
int n3;
do {
    n3 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
} while (n3 == n2 || n3 == n1);
```

The `do` loop is guaranteed to run at least once.

Comment: yes but i can't use this code because, i'm studing java for first time ad i'm at chapter 5 of my book and until now on the book are explained the cycle and the if-else iteration

Comment: So you're not allowed to use `Collection`s at all? What about arrays?

Comment: no, only cycle or if-else if it's needed

Comment: Ok, edited my answer to account for your course's quirks...

Comment: Using set for generating unique numbers is inefficient. Preferred way to generate unique numbers is Fisher-Yates algorithm.